# Should extracurricular activities be mentioned on a CV?

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

As a student I have taken extracurricular courses related to my major, should I list them on my CV?

In case it is helpful: I am on the third year. I am majoring in computer science and have taken extracurricular courses on Internet security, Evolutionary computing and Web programming.

Comment: Thank you Dukeling for sharing that link, it contains answers that are relevant to my question. But I believe this question has a broader scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mister, you should *put everything on your resume which is true, relevant, and beneficial*.

Having been a hiring manager at several different companies, I can offer some perspective.  I am always pleased to see someone pursuing education.  Especially relevant education.  Especially if that someone went out of his way to take these classes.

I am also interested in relevant hobby programming (if programming is related to the role I have an opening for).  If you have written your own version of pac-man just for kicks, I'll be impressed.  Honestly, it's one of the signs that you have a technologist on your hands!

Comment: I have seen position descriptions where the hiring company specified to the job agency to present only candidates with hobbies or interest supporting "handy" skills.

Comment: Thanks a lot akaioi for the great answer. It is great to know from someone who has been a hiring manager that they value this kind of things.

Comment: @L.Dutch [nod nod nod] I've seen similar, but thought that that is going too far -- some talented people just have different hobbies.  Plus that kind of policy tends to bias your candidate pool toward younger devs.  I like a mix of ages.

Answer (score 1):

The "relevance" test when determining whether something should go on your CV is relative to the job you're applying for so assuming you are applying for a role that is IT or development related then go for it. They will look great on the CV in my opinion. If you were applying for something completely different then their "value" so to speak decreases, becoming more about showing work ethic then skills or experience.

Later on as you gain relevant work experience this will start to superceed these courses and you'll want to reduce their prominence before probably dropping them off altogether but for now they are a valuable bit of gravy on the meat of your major as it were.

Comment: Great answer, thank you motosubatsu. What do you mean by work ethic?

Comment: By that I mean it shows that you were prepared to do more "work" than was strictly required of you. Employers tend to like that sort of thing